# Free field (Wakimoto) representation in 2d CFT

Tags: quantum-field-theory, conformal-field-theory, representation-theory, lie-algebra, affine-lie-algebra

This question is more a request for explanations. I'm reading now the [Di Francesco book](http://gen.lib.rus.ec/book/index.php?md5=97542E7152ED4487EA5696D328AC9EC3) in attempt to understand how the free field representations of 2d CFTs are constructed. The first steps in constructing the Wakimoto representation seem natural to me:

[image]

What authors say later about $\beta_0$ and $\gamma_0$ does not surprise me as well - indeed, it seems plausible to replace them with Laurent polynomials in order for their zero modes to obey the original Lie algebra, while the polynomials themselves - the corresponding vertex algebra.

However, the part about $p$ and $q$ confuses me a lot - I would never guess these steps myself:

[image]

Why do we need the vacuum of the Fock space to be the eigenvector of the operator $p$? Why don't we just start with some $|0\rangle$?

And why does $p$ have to take its values in the weight lattice of $su(2)$?? (confuses me most...)

Basically, why do we need the operators / fields $p$ and $q$ in order to construct the representation? Why not just $\beta$ and $\gamma$, while keeping $j$ a number?

Comment: Perhaps you wish to contrast to the [Segal-Bargmann space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Segal–Bargmann_space). You are instructed to embed spin j modules of su(2) in the infinite dimensional Fock space $1,x,x^2,x^3,....$, the module of the infinite-dimensional Heisenberg Lie algebra, so to find a device to pick a highest state $x^{2j+1}$ in it. In so many words, $|p;0\rangle$ specifies the lowest state, 1, of the specific module with highest state $x^{2j+1}$. If you follow the math, why is the language, sheer renaming, bothering you?

Comment: A more tastefully symmetric embedding of su(2) modules in Fock space is the original variant of this, the celebrated 3/4 -century [Holstein-Primakoff transformation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Holstein–Primakoff_transformation).  (Their *s* is your *j*.)

Comment: You are calling the space of polynomials in $x$ "the module of the Heisenberg Lie algebra". But in this case I would expect the operators $\hat{x}$ and $\hat{p}$ to be defined in the usual way, $\hat{x} = x \cdot$, $~~\hat{p}=-i\dfrac{\operatorname{d}}{\operatorname{d}x}$.

Comment: Also, why do we need a special 'device' to fit the spin-$j$ $su(2)$ module into the Heisenberg one? The operators (15.268) are designed in such a way that, besides the correct commutation relations, the condition (15.271) is satisfied automatically, and the monimial $x^{2j+1}$ is annihilated by $f_0$...

Comment: NO, *don't* expect the hatted *new variables* to have anything to do with the x variable of *γ, β*. Baaad language! The hatted variables are a gimmick to read off and project into the weight/spin lattice of the *j*s, is all... Yes, the structure is self-explanatory, except for an ugly nonhermiticity twist, and it is *just* the Holstein-Primakoff map (above) you probably learned about in college, in  pompous mathematese....

Comment: Actually, this map has a name, even [Dyson-Maleev](http://physics.stackexchange.com/a/43276/66086)... so you appreciate there is an infinity of such....