# What are the relations between a ladder algebra and an $SU(2)$ algebra?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, magnetic-fields, geometry, lie-algebra, quantum-hall-effect

I am studying elementary models of the Quantum Hall Effect. I don't have a strong background in Lie algebras so I was hoping someone could elaborate on the following observation:

For a free particle constrained to a plane with a uniform magnetic field oriented normal to the plane its Hamiltonian can be written in the same form as that of a quantum harmonic oscillator:
$$H = \hbar \omega_B (a^\dagger a + 1/2).$$ There will also be another mutually commuting set of bosonic creation/annihilation operators $[b,b^\dagger]$ indexing the particle's angular momentum if you choose a symmetric gauge for the vector potential.

Solve a similar problem with a particle on a sphere surrounding a magnetic monopole, and you find instead of two mutually commuting "ladder algebras" (by the way is there an official name for this?) a representation of $SU(2) \times SU(2)$; something like

$$H \propto S^- S^+ + 1/2$$

along with another set $[L^i,L^j] = \mathrm{i} \epsilon^{ijk} L^k$ from which you can also define raising and lowering operators $L^+,L^-.$

Can someone elucidate what's happening here from a geometric/algebraic point of view? I can follow the standard calculations but do not have a good image of the "big picture."

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/41485/2451

Comment: Perhaps I should change my title; my question (re: the last sentence in my post) is not at all answered by that derivation.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Holstein-Primakoff and Dyson-Maleev representation](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/41485/holstein-primakoff-and-dyson-maleev-representation). Also: these notes are useful: http://www.physics.drexel.edu/~bob/LieGroups/LG_06.pdf (e.g. problem 1 at pag. 104)