# Holstein Primakoff - Showing Spin-Relation $S^2 = S(S+1)$

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, angular-momentum, quantum-spin

I'm trying to prove that Holstein-Primakoff-Transformation
\begin{align}
S_i^{+} &= \sqrt{2S-n_i}b_i \\
S_i^{-} &= b_i^{\dagger} \sqrt{2S -n_i} \\
S_i^{z} &= S-n_i
\end{align}

holds the condition $$ \vec S^2=S(S+1)$$ but I get the following (with $S_x=\frac{1}{2}( S^+ + S^-) $ und $S_y=\frac{1}{2i} (S^+-S^-)$):
\begin{align*}
S^{2} &= S_x^{2} + S_y^{2} + S_z^{2} = \frac{1}{4} \left( S^{+} + S^{-}\right)^{2} - \frac{1}{4} (S^{+}- S^{-})^{2} + (S-n_i)^{2}  \\
&= \frac{1}{4} (2 S^{+} S^{-} + 2 S^{-} S^{+}) + S^{2} - 2Sn_i + n_i^{2} \\
&= \frac{1}{2} \left(  \sqrt{2S-n_i} b_ib_i^{\dagger} \sqrt{2S-n_i} + b_i^{\dagger}(2S-n_i) b_i \right) + S^{2} - 2Sn_i + n_i^{2}  \\
&=  \frac{1}{2} \left(  \sqrt{2S-n_i}(1+n_i) \sqrt{2S-n_i} + b_i^{\dagger}(2S-n_i) b_i \right) + S^{2} - 2Sn_i + n_i^{2}  \\
&=   \frac{1}{2} \left( n_i (2S-n_i) + 2S -n_i + b_i^{\dagger}(2S-n_i) b_i \right) + S^{2} - 2Sn_i + n_i^{2} \\
&= S^{2} + \frac{n_i^{2}}{2} + S - \frac{n_i}{2} - \frac{1}{2} b_i^{\dagger} b_i^{\dagger} b_i b_i 
\end{align*}
So my question is, whether the Holstein-Primakoff satisfies this condition or not? - It should satisifies the condition, because otherwise it would be unphysically to use this transformation.

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/41485/2451

Comment: Oh yes there is a big mistake. I try to fix it.

Comment: @Leviathan you've been making edits every 15 seconds...  why not tak5 15 minutes to work it out completely and without errors before posting?

Comment: I'm totally sorry. I thought I had calculated it right, but as I posted it I saw the first mistakes, and then it goes on an on... Next time I will handle this way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you've done is treat $n_i$ as a number, which is not completely honest, since it really an operator $\hat n$.  Thus for instance
\begin{align}
S^+ \vert n\rangle &= \sqrt{2S-\hat n}\, b\vert n\rangle = 
\sqrt{2S-\hat n} \sqrt{n}\vert n-1\rangle = \sqrt{(2S-n+1)n}\vert n-1\rangle\\
S^- \vert n\rangle &= b^\dagger \sqrt{2S-\hat n} \vert n\rangle
=  \sqrt{(2S-n)(n+1)} \vert n+1\rangle
\end{align}
so that
\begin{align}
S^+S^-\vert n\rangle &=
\sqrt{(2S-n)(n+1)}  S^+  \vert n+1\rangle
=\sqrt{(2S-n)(n+1)} \sqrt{(2S-n)(n+1)}  \vert n\rangle \\
&=(2S-n)(n+1) \vert n\rangle \\
S^-S^+\vert n\rangle 
&=(2S-n+1)n \vert n\rangle\, .
\end{align} 
If my algebra is right this should take care of it.

Comment: I don't see where you get the +1 in the first term. $$S^+ \vert n\rangle = \sqrt{2S-\hat n}\, b\vert n\rangle = 
\sqrt{2S-\hat n} \sqrt{n}\vert n-1\rangle =\mathbf{ \sqrt{(2S-n+1)n}} \vert n-1\rangle $$ and secondly I don't think I ever treat the number operator ever as number in my calculation. I only changed the position of $n_i$ if and only if the term before is an polynomial of $n_i$, because that commutes with $n_i$.

Comment: well.. $\hat n\vert n-1\rangle = (n-1)\vert n-1\rangle$ so $\sqrt{2S-\hat n}\vert n-1\rangle = \sqrt{2S-(n-1)}\vert n-1\rangle = \sqrt{2S-n+1}\vert n-1\rangle$

Comment: @Leviathan maybe indeed you never treated $n$ as a number but  you've edited your question so much that if you ever did this all traces of your incorrect manipulations of $n$ have by now disappeared.

Comment: I think there was one mistake with $b_i$ treated as number, not $n_i$ that I corrected. Next time should I not correct mistakes in my question?

Comment: @Leviathan don't worry about it.  No sense in trying to figure out what went wrong so many edits ago.